# convert text to image on razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I want to convert a string of data that is passed into my controller to an image file like `.jpeg` or `.png`. I know, in the past, ASP.NET use to support `Bitmap`, but now in .NET Core, `Bitmap` doesn't seem to be supported. When I wrote the code below

```
        Bitmap bmp = new(100, 100);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {

            Font font = new Font("Journal", 20.0f);
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), 0, 0);


        }
        return bmp;
```

here, I am getting an error saying that `graphics.DrawString` is only supported on Windows.
How can I convert a text to an image in .NET Core with Razor frontend?

Comment: To create an image from text in a cross-platform way in .NET Core, you can use a third-party library like SixLabors.ImageSharp

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action

Comment: You might find this example useful; https://swharden.com/blog/2022-05-25-maui-graphics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed nuget Package `System.Drawing.Common`. No error appears after build in asp.net core project.